# jQuery before.()/prependTo () errors

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a site for experiment and I am having trouble with some code.

The next button works but the previous button doesn't. It basically swaps the first two divs with the class "tri" but not the other one.

I cannot understand why one works and the other one doesn't.

I have tried prependTo and before but neither work properly?

Feel free to look at the code here:

HTML: http://epicgiggle.co.uk/test/-testtwo/index.html

CSS: http://epicgiggle.co.uk/test/-testtwo/style.css

jQuery: http://epicgiggle.co.uk/test/-testtwo/custom.js

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code here and/or use a site like http://jsfiddle.net where we can examine and modify the code in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a lot of work you're doing, moving the text and CSS attributes individually. Far easier to move the divs themselves. ([`.insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore) and [`.insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter) are the methods you need in this particular case.)

```
$(".prev").click(function() {
        $('.tri').last().insertBefore( $('.tri').first() );
});
$(".next").click(function() {
        $('.tri').first().insertAfter( $('.tri').last() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Dnwvy/2/

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was asking for/wanted. Thanks to everyone else that contributed also. I have now learnt what an amateur coder I am (good job it's not my profession!!!)

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/otabes/3/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Here is a correction and simplification of your jQuery:

```
var dh = $('.tri').height();

$(function() {
    $("p.content").css('padding-top', (dh/3.5));
    $("#title").text(currentDiv.attr('title'));
});


$("title").text( $("div.tri").first().attr('title'));

$(".prev, .next").click(function() {
  
  var $first = $('.tri').first();
  var $last = $('.tri').last();
  
  if( $(this).hasClass('next') ){
    $first.insertAfter( $last );
  }else{
    $last.insertBefore( $first );
  }
  
  $("#title").css('color', ( $("div.tri").first().css('background-color') ) );
  $("#title").text( $("div.tri").first().attr('title') ); 
  
});
```

you had extra `{ }` in your markup and some missing `#` under `title`.

In your HTML: you **cannot** have 3 same `p#content` elements! ID is unique per page. Use `class` instead (Change in your CSS respectively.)

**your html:**

```
<div class="title"><p id="title">One</p></div>
<div class="prev"><p>Prev</p></div>
<div class="next"><p>Next</p></div>
  
<div class="tri" id="one" title="One"><p style="padding-top: 57.1429px;" class="content">Content One</p></div>
<div class="tri" id="two" title="Two"><p style="padding-top: 57.1429px;" class="content">Content Two</p></div>
<div class="tri" id="three" title="Three"><p style="padding-top: 57.1429px;" class="content">Content Three</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the whole title thing was to change the tab title (e.g. page title). Cheers for the CSS thing, I'm still learning but the help along the way is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also see another odd thing.

in the first line you have

```
$(document).ready(function(){....
```

and after a while in the body of the anonymous function you have

```
$(function(){.....
```

which means

```
$(document).load(function().....
```

if the doc is in ready state, then the load event will not be fired again, I think.
I would place all the code inside the load event event like that

```
$(function() {

var dh = $('.tri').height();
var currentDiv;
var previousDiv;

$("p#content").css('padding-top', (dh/3.5));
$("#title").text(currentDiv.attr('title'));

currentDiv = $("div.tri").first();
lastDiv = $("div.tri").last();
$("title").text(currentDiv.attr('title'));
$(".prev").click(function() {
        lastDiv.before(currentDiv);
        lastDiv = $("div.tri").first();
        $("#title").text(currentDiv.attr('title'));
        $("#title").css('color', (currentDiv.css('background-color')));
        $("title").text(currentDiv.attr('title'));
});
$(".next").click(function(){
        $(currentDiv).appendTo('body');
        currentDiv = $("div.tri").first();
        $("#title").text(currentDiv.attr('title'));
        $("#title").css('color', (currentDiv.css('background-color')));
        $("title").text(currentDiv.attr('title'));
});

});
```

(paranthesis may mismatch...)

Comment: `$(function () { })` is shorthand for `.ready()`, not `.load()`. Also, `ready` fires before `load`. `ready` is when the DOM is accessible via Javascript, `load` is when everything has been rendered.